How to deploy Docusaurus site from subfolder (not root) of repository
I want to place all of my Docusaurus site files into a subfolder called website inside my project repo and have my site deploy properly.
I have noticed Docusaurus sites that have done this (for example facebook/docusarus).
I want this file structure:
GitLab Project Root
├── File 1
├── File 2 
├── File 3
├── File 4
└── website-folder 
    └── Docusaurus site files

However I am not sure:

What files must remain at the project root for the site to deploy correctly?
What must change in the YAML or config files for this to work?
What else am I not considering?

Here is my test site: https://gitlab.com/jrbauhaus/my-website
I tried restructuring the repository and updating the YAML file but I'm not sure where to start.
Updated my .gitlab-ci.yml file to the below and still got a build error:
image: node:latest

cache:
  paths:
    - website/node_modules/

before_script:
  - cd website
  - npm install

stages:
  - build
  - deploy

build:
  stage: build
  script:
    - npm run build
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - website/build

pages:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - yarn build:gitlab
    - yarn build:gitlab --output-dir ../public
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - public
  only:
    - main


Build error:
          at loadSiteConfig (/builds/jrbauhaus/my-website/website/node_modules/@docusaurus/core/lib/server/config.js:39:62)
    at async Promise.all (index 1)
    at async loadContext (/builds/jrbauhaus/my-website/website/node_modules/@docusaurus/core/lib/server/site.js:33:97)
    at async getLocalesToBuild (/builds/jrbauhaus/my-website/website/node_modules/@docusaurus/core/lib/commands/build.js:79:21)
    at async Command.build (/builds/jrbauhaus/my-website/website/node_modules/@docusaurus/core/lib/commands/build.js:58:21)
[INFO] Docusaurus version: 3.3.2
Node version: v22.3.0
Cleaning up project directory and file based variables
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1

Any thoughts? I still can't really find a simple explanation of how to deploy a Docusaurus site from a subfolder within the root/base of a repository. As in: No raw folders at the base of the repo


What files must remain at the Project root for the site to deploy correctly?
You need to build your page and then move everything to the root of the repo under the public repo:

Your app must output files to the public folder. If you create this folder during the build pipeline, you do not need to commit it to Git.


What must change in the .yml or config files for this to work?


 image: node:latest

cache:
 paths:
   - website/node_modules/

before_script:
 - cd website
 - npm install

stages:
 - build
 - deploy

build:
 stage: build
 script:
   - npm run build
 artifacts:
   paths:
     - website/build

pages:
 stage: deploy
 script:
   - yarn install # It's strange that you're using yarn here and the before_script will try to run npm install first
   - yarn build:gitlab
   - mv website/build ../public # You can also get rid of this line and use yarn build:gitlab --output-dir ../public
 artifacts:
   paths:
     - public
 only:
   - main



thanks for the reply. It's my understanding that the json file and the GitLab yaml file need to be at the root of the repo, but the rest of my folders are in the public folder, I believe.

Which JSON file are you referring to? The .gitlab-ci.yaml needs to be on the root of the repo yeah

the package.json file.
In this example, you can see that file is still at the root of the repo

— I updated my .gitlab-ci.yml to this: GitLab link
...
Got an error: GitLab link

— any thoughts on my latest comment?

The error does not seem to be related to GitLab at all, but the docusaurus config which I cannot help with. Also the CI file has two yarn build commands, you should use only one

I had the same problem,
and below is what worked for me.
Just try:

You do not need to make public dir.
You do not need to manage build dir on GitLab.
Just merge to main branch.
You can publish.

.gitlab-ci.yml
image: node:22.3.0

pages:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - mkdir public
    - npm --prefix ./website-folder install ./website-folder
    - cd my-website
    - npm run build
    - cp -r ./build/**  ../public/
  artifacts:
    paths:
    - public
  only:
  - main


Gotcha. What Docusaurus files did you keep at the root? The .gitlab-ci.yml needs to be at the root, but is that it?

RE: Deploying Docusaurus Site from Subfolder in GitLab Repo/Directory
I found a fix for this.
If you want to deploy your docusuarus site, for example, from a folder called website as the root of your repo/directory, you must make some adjustments to your .gitlab-ci.yml file
Here's what works if your Docusaurus site is in subfolder called "website" at the root of your GitLab repo:
image: node:20.13.1

cache:
  paths:
    - website/node_modules/

before_script:
  - cd website
  - npm install --ignore-engines # may remove `ignore-engines`

stages:
  - build
  - deploy

build:
  stage: build
  script:
    - chmod +x node_modules/.bin/docusaurus
    - npm run build
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - website/build

pages:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - npm install --ignore-engines
    - chmod +x node_modules/.bin/docusaurus
    - yarn build:gitlab
    # - yarn build:gitlab --output-dir ../public
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - public
  only:
    - main

Lots of troubleshooting. Certainly, there simpler, more optimal ways to define a .gitlab-ci.yml file, but this WILL work.
NOTE: Instead of defining your node image as "latest," like I see in many tutorials, etc. I would define the explicit node version your site build uses. For example, image: node:20:13:1
REMINDER: Don't forget to add your build:gitlab line to your package.json file:
"build:gitlab": "docusaurus build --out-dir public",

